# linq-leftjoin with multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have facing some issues when trying to get a left join result with 2 tables
its showing some enumeration errors.  Here I have 2 tables -specs and users.It shows some error when iterate  over resultant result

```
class Program
        {
            class Specs
        {
            public int specId { get; set; }
            public string desc { get; set; }
            public int createdby { get; set; }
            public int lastupdatedby { get; set; }
        }

        class Users
        {
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public string username { get; set; }
        }

        class UpdatedUser
        {
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public string username { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var specs = new Specs[]
                {
                new Specs{specId = 1, desc = "Spec1", createdby=1, lastupdatedby=1},
                new Specs{specId = 2, desc = "Spec2", createdby=2, lastupdatedby=3},
                new Specs{specId = 3, desc = "Spec3", createdby=3, lastupdatedby=1},
                new Specs{specId = 4, desc = "Spec4", createdby=3, lastupdatedby=3},
            };

            var user = new Users[]
            {
                new Users{userId = 1, username = "User1"},
                new Users{userId = 2, username = "User2"},
            };

           var abc= specs.GroupJoin(user.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                s => s.lastupdatedby,
                u => u.userId,
                (s, u) => u.Select(x=>new{ specs = s, users = x })
                .Select(x => new {
                    specId = x.specs.specId,
                    desc = x.specs.desc,
                    createdby = x.specs.createdby,
                    username = x.users.username

                })).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @arekzyla System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[ConsoleApp1.Program+Users,<>f__AnonymousType1`4[System.Int32,System.String,System.Int32,System.String]]

Comment: It's not an error. That's just lazy IEnumerable.

Comment: You can add ToList right after Select: `.Select(x => new { ... }).ToList() to have a list

Comment: @arekzyla,I think hve already using 'Tolinq' in last portion of my query

Comment: No you haven't. The last line should be: `}).ToList()).ToList();`

Comment: What's the expected result here, query is compiling, you may have to use `SelectMany`